# In Java, is it possible to use a type variable, as an array element, inside an Interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

In Java, is it possible to use a type variable, as an array element, inside an Interface?

I've tried as a filed type and as a cast operator, but always get the error

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type A

```
interface ITest<A> {
    A[] j; // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type A
    Object[] = (A[]) new Object[3]; // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type A
}
```

Is there any case, where I am able to use the construct `A[]` inside the interface (and in an enum type?)?

```
class CTest<A> {
    enum MyEnum {
        F, G, H;
        // something that uses A[] inside. Getting the same error as above
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in interfaces [are implicitly public, static and final](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.3), they're basically constants. And you can't have constants that depend on a type parameter because in Java parameters are removed from the type on compilation.

By the way, this is independent of whether you're using an array or not,

```
public interface X<T> {
    T c = (T)new AnyType();
}
```

won't work either. And neither would

```
public class X<T> {
  public static final T c = (T)new AnyType();
}
```

Comment: I can't find the relevant part of the JLS but member enums, like member interfaces are implicitly static, thus they aren't allowed to use type information of the enclosing class either.

Comment: @biziclop: You're right. Nested enums are static. Didn't remember that.

Comment: @biziclop, Do u mean that any variable define in interface which is a built-in datatype is public, static and final implicitly?and another question what do u mean by "all paramenters are removed from the type on compilation"?

Comment: @Alaa Yes, any field declared in an interface will be publis, static and final. But I'm afraid I can't explain it to you how type erasure exactly works,

Comment: @biziclop- No problem, but If u ever find website descibe it, can u please post it here?

Comment: @Alaa Maybe this will help: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generic array type in an interface, like this:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    void doSomething(T[] array);
}
```

Your problem was you were trying to declare a *field* in an interface, which you basically can't do other than for constants. You can't declare a *field* of a generic array type in an interface, but I'd hope that you wouldn't want to anyway.

Admittedly type erasure makes the combination of arrays and generics somewhat awkward in various situations, but I think the above at least answers the question you posed.

Comment: Yes, I remembered that option. I forgot to mention I was trying to use `A[]` inside a field initializer.

Comment: @John: Why do you want a field in an interface? That's almost always a bad idea. Having an array field in a class *implementing* an interface is one thing - but in the interface itself? I'm struggling to imagine how that would turn out well.

Comment: This is not something I'm using. I just need to know if it possible.

Comment: @John: Okay, in that case the answer is that I don't believe it is. Basically static fields and generics don't go well together, as there isn't really a static variable per "constructed type".